# Error with creating an outputfile .rdstate() returns value 2

Tags: c++

As in the topic, while I execute the following code .rdstate() returns value 2. What do I do wrong?

```
string logger_path_and_name("\"F:\\windowsqnx\\loggs\\logger_file.dat");

/* file to store simulation data */
std::ofstream fout( logger_path_and_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

/* check if ios::binary supported */
if (!fout.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "can't create file logger_file.dat\n";
    std::cerr << fout.rdstate();
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: First guess: putting the quote into the string is bad. I'd try: `"F:\\windowsqnx\\loggs\logger_file.dat"`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"\"F:\\windowsqnx\\loggs\\logger_file.dat"
```

Your issue is that this turns into `"F:\windowsqnx\loggs\logger_file.dat`. As you can see, you have  an orphan `"` at the beginning.

You can fix this in two ways.
1. Place another `\"` at the end.
2. Remove the `\"` at the beginning

On a side note, ios::rdstate returns a Bitmask type and the  way you retrieve the information is by using `bitwise AND or OR` with the [iostate flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/).

Example that was shamefully stolen from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/):

```
// getting state of stream object
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ifstream is;
  is.open ("test.txt");
  if ( (is.rdstate() & ifstream::failbit ) != 0 )
    cerr << "Error opening 'test.txt'\n";
  return 0;
}
```